# ionic 3 dynamic ngModel using empty object

Tags: ionic3

Did anyone is able to solve this problem.

I have empty object like this:- initial stage ->model_obj:any={}
and i want to create dynamic ngmodel in form using
formarry = [1,2,3]

I am trying to create dynamic obj like below but got error like cannot read 
property of 0 undefined.

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let forma of formarry; let i=index">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>
      <label class="form-title">Title Of Qualification</label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-12>
      <input type="text" name="qualification_name" 
       [(ngModel)]="model_obj[i][qualification_name]" placeholder="Enter 
       Qualification" class="form-input" />
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: Did anyone is able to solve this problem.

Comment: can u try like this in line 1 and 7
Line 1 :  `<ion-row *ngFor="let forma of formarry; let i=index;model_obj[i] =[]">`

Line 7 : `<input type="text" name="qualification_name" 
       [(ngModel)]="model_obj[i]['qualification_name']" placeholder="Enter 
       Qualification" class="form-input" />`

Comment: I need dynamic key also. In my ts file i declared model_obj as object at initial stage like this i.e model_obj:any={};

Comment: I tried but got error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
    </ion-row> -->

    <ion-row [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let forma of model_obj; let i=index; model_obj[i] = []">

Comment: try to do the following
in template
`<ion-row *ngFor="let forma of formarry; trackBy: myFunc; let i=index">`

in controller

`myFunc(index, forma) {
        this.model_obj[index]  = [];
    }`

Comment: and what about line 7 it remain same?

Comment: Cannot set property '0' of undefined without any changes in line7